# Rendering pdf with pdf js

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, pdf.js

Im trying to render pdf using pdfjs library but I got stuck: Im using it in an IONIC app. Below is my code :

```
import { PDFJS } from "pdfjs-dist";

renderPDF(url, canvasContainer) {


var options = options || { scale: 1 };

function renderPage(page) {
  var viewport = page.getViewport(options.scale);
  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var renderContext = {
    canvasContext: ctx,
    viewport: viewport
  };

  canvas.height = viewport.height;
  canvas.width = viewport.width;
  canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);

  page.render(renderContext);
}

function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
  for(var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++)
    pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
}
console.log(PDFJS)
PDFJS.disableWorker = true;
PDFJS.getDocument(url).then(renderPages);
```

}

I am calling it in NgOnInit, the problem Im having is with PDFJS field, as it says Cannot set property 'disableWorker' of undefined
    at DrawingPage.webpackJsonp.155.DrawingPage.renderPDF. Im thinking its something with import but can get it done right..

Comment: How did you install the pdfjs-dist? What do the contents look like? And could you provide a link to that repo? Have you tried importing it like `import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';`

Comment: damn I was about to try this different import approach and forgot about it, it seems to work now :D thanks, maybe post answer so i can upvote

Comment: Haha, thanks I appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing your import like the way you're doing it means that the file you're importing must have an export called `PDFJS`, which it might not. To import the whole file and place whatever is exported into a variable, you can use this import format: `import * as PDFJS from 'pdfjs-dist';`